# getElementsByTagName returns array with null elements

Tags: html, dom, tampermonkey

I have this Tampermonkey script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Remove strong tags
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  remove answers
// @author       You
// @match        http://*/*
// @grant        GM_log
// @run-at       document-end
// ==/UserScript==

setTimeout((function() {
    'use strict';

    var allStrong = document.getElementsByTagName("strong");
    GM_log(allStrong);

    for (var i=0, max=allStrong.length; i < max; i++) {
        var strong = allStrong.item(i);
        GM_log(strong);
        if(strong && strong.parentNode.tagName == "LI") {
            strong.parentNode.appendChild(strong.firstChild);
            strong.parentNode.removeChild(strong);
        }
    }
})(), 5000);
```

Out of 8 `strong` tags that fit the criteria, it only replaces 4.

This is printed in the Chrome console.

[image]

The array when first printed has 8 elements, but then the last 4 elements are printed as `undefined`.

Why is this happening?

I don't think the problem comes from the code being executed before the full page load, because I put a large timeout.

[This](http://jayendrapatil.com/aws-vpc-endpoints/) is the page where I'm running it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a so-called live `NodeList`, not a static `Array` - it means that it contains up-to-date results of your query.

So, after each of your iterations, one of the elements is removed as it is no longer `<strong>` element.

You have 2 choices here:

- Transform `NodeList` into normal `Array` (eg. by using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from))
- Always access first element of your `NodeList`

Answer (score 2):

The first printout shows 8 elements because it's what it is at that point. But it is an **HTMLCollection**, and in the HTML DOM it is live; it is automatically updated when the underlying document is changed.

The for loop removes some of these `<strong>` nodes as it goes (`strong.parentNode.removeChild(strong);`), but only evaluates the length of the collection at the beginning (`max=allStrong.length`). So it will still run 8 times, but by the time it reaches half, it iterates over nothing.

When you *expand* the first line of logs, Chrome evaluates your live HTMLCollection, which by that point only contains 4 elements, so it shows only 4. The little (i) at the end of the line tells you when this expression was evaluated.

If you want to see all this play out in real time, instead of putting it in a `setTimeout`, I'd suggest adding the following statement in your code, wherever you want to start looking at it step by step:

```
debugger;
```